# MPI Win_post/start/complete/wait with OpenMP endless waiting

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

I am trying to combine MPI one sided communication with OpenMP tasks.
The program sets up a cartesian communication and communicates some data. Without the OpenMp parts everthing works fine. Here is the code with OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    MPI_Win_post(neighbour_group, 0, win_src);
    MPI_Win_start(neighbour_group, 0, win_src);

#pragma omp task
    {
        MPI_Put(...);
        MPI_Put(...);
        MPI_Put(...);
        MPI_Put(...);
        MPI_Win_complete(win_src); // All Puts done
        cout << rank << " complete." << endl;
    }

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for (auto row_index = 0; row_index < rows; row_index++) {
        // do more stuff
    }

    cout << rank << " waiting." << endl;
    MPI_Win_wait(win_src);
    cout << rank << " waiting finished." << endl;

    // do even more stuff
    MPI_Allreduce(...);
}
```

it results in some MPI processes not being able to reach the MPI_Win_complete(), hence the MPI_Win_wait() never finishes. So the problem seems to be with post and put already.
Also to be mentioned is, that I am using OpenMPI to run the code.

My question is, if there are some caveats I am not aware of and/or if there is a flaw in the code.

I tried:

- taskgroups, barriers, taskwaits in several combinations
- closing and opening the parallel region

Comment: The code looks dubious; surely the `omp single` should only be for the task creation, and what is the point of creating a single task? Plus nested parallelism is often a bad idea, and seems unnecessary here (if the loop wasn't in the `omp single` you could use `omp for`), and there is no task synchronisation point, so the `MPI_Put` calls need not finish before the other MPI calls are made.

Comment: I want the execution of the Puts and the for loop to overlap, hence the task. Please keep in mind that the Puts are not async, so it would be a waste of time to let the Puts be done by one single thread, while the rest is waiting to start with the for loop. I also know that the foor loop like this is not performant and needs some other scheduling (edited this now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default MPI is not aware of other threads, and this makes problems with the calls to MPI_Win_put(...) that might not come from the MPI process, but from an omp thread.
MPI can be initialized being aware of threads, more to that here https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node303.htm
Unfortunately the OpenMPI version we currently run does not allow  MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE.